# Informix connection speed - Informatica PowerCenter vs Python by JDBC

Tags: python, jdbc, informix, informatica

I have one workflow in Informatica Powercenter for transferring data between Informix and Oracle.
Informatica needs about 20 seconds to do this work (6 tables, daily updates filtred by current date).

I tried to achieve the same in Python using JDBC... And this way it's extremely slow...

For example, the first of these tables - it's about 100000 rows/day - in Python fetching even 10000 rows takes about a minute.

Is it normal that Informatica is so much quicker? Can I somehow speed up my Python script?

example:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver",
                           "jdbc:informix-sqli://server:port/cms:INFORMIXSERVER=x;user=x;password=x",
                           ["chancel", "chancel"],
                           r"C:\app\informix-jdbc-complete-4.50.4.1.jar")

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from table")
curs.fetchall()
```

Comment: What's the total count of rows in this table? Python will load it all into memory, possibly spilling to disk, which might slow the script by a lot.

Comment: As already mentioned here, there could be lots of reasons why you see a different in performance between the two drivers.
Try playing around with FET_BUF_SIZE (like adding "fet_buf_size=32000" to your connection string) that should improve things.
Also SQLIDEBUG/SQLIPRINT can be used to know how the clients (Informatica vs JDBC) are running the SQL query and give you an idea of how to optimize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple factors can be a reason for 'Why Informatica is faster' -

1. Informatica can use native drivers like Oracle or Informix drivers to connect directly to the server. These are way faster than a JDBC driver.
2. Informatica uses multi-threading to connect to the source, do the transformation, and load into the target, so it's faster than Python (which follows a procedural approach).
3. Informatica is built for this kind of ETL, so it's an optimized tool for any ETL type operations - memory and, process optimized. And you can control memory parameters when the data size is bigger. It can also create indexes etc. to make loading faster.
4. Python doesn't work well for larger table processing because it needs to hold all in memory and it also needs a powerful CPU.

Comment: Thanks! I tried ODBC and it seems to be way faster than JDBC in my case, thats everything i need :)